# Using a main factory?

Tags: php

So I am trying to require a model, and I want to do it the right way. Am I doing this right?

```
<?php
 class Factory
       {
             public function buildModel($model) 
             {
                   require MODELS . $model . '.php';
                   return new ucfirst($model):
             }
       }
```

And in my controller

```
public function create()
      {
             ...
             $model = $this->factory->buildModel('user');
             $model->save();
      }
```

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I am building my own framework to grasp OOP and MVC. I have tried redoing it 2 other times but just can't get it right. @Matt

Comment: If it's your own framework, then it's an approach as good as any other. Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: Well I'm still trying to understand the OOP and MVC design patterns, and was wondering if I was using the factory pattern correctly. @this.lau_

Comment: If what you are asking is if there's any right way to do it, then this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks ok; some improvements maybe?

I suspect your want to pass arguments or dependency inject other objects into the loaded models, your user class might need database access, or routing?:

Also `$this->model->load()` would more suit.

```
<?php 
public function create()
{
    ...

    $model = $this->model->load('user', $something, $something_else);
    $model->save();
}
?>
```

So the model loader would look like:

```
<?php 
class model{

    /**
     * model loader 
     */
    private function load()
    {
        // retrieve passed arguments
        $args = func_get_args();
        // delete the first argument which is the class name
        $class = array_shift($args);
        try
        {
            $path = MODELS . $class . '.php';

            if (file_exists($path))
            {
                require_once ($path);
                $ref = new ReflectionClass(basename($class));
                return $ref->newInstanceArgs($args);
            } else
            {
                throw new Exception('Model class not found: ' . htmlentities($path));
            }

        }
        catch (exception $e)
        {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
?>
```

and the user class would get the construct arguments like so,

```
<?php
Class user{

    function __construct($something, $something_else){
        $this->something = $something;
        $this->something_else = $something_else;
    }

    function save(){
        //yada

    }
    ...
}
?>
```

Comment: But why would I make a model class if there would only be one method in there?

Comment: You dont need fat classes just because... A single method is fine in a class, but you could do it like `$this->factory->loadModel()` I suppose.

Comment: no probs, good luck on your project

Comment: Also what would I want to inject to the user model?

Comment: *Dependency injection*, Perhaps a database connection, routing values or a registry class. You could even pass the Factory object and be able to load models inside the models.